# Save a value inside several lines to an array

Tags: php

I'm doing a little php script and i have a form that saves several things on a txt.

I need to read all the lines and take the last value of each and put them all inside an array

I was thinking that i could do that with the explode function but i don't know how to implement it several times to sum all the values and get the average.

```
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $edad=$_POST['edad'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $importe=$_POST['importe'];
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];


//this part writes each value of the form to a txt file separated by an " | "
// this is where I need help. I have to show the sum of all the $importe values in all of the lines in the txt
//

$miarchivo=fopen("resultados.txt","a");
    if(!($miarchivo))
    {
    print("Imposible abrir archivo");
    exit;
    }
    fputs($miarchivo,"    $nombre | $edad | $email | $importe \n" .PHP_EOL);
    fclose($miarchivo);
    //echo "<script>location.href='forma.php'</script>";


//This part only shows the values of the txt after the script ends
$miarchivo=fopen("resultados.txt","r");
    if
    (! ($miarchivo))
    {
        print("no hay resultados");
        exit;
    }
    while(!feof($miarchivo)){
        $linea=fgets($miarchivo,255);
        print"$linea<BR>";
    }
    fclose($miarchivo);
```

I expect to get an array like:

```
tab [0] $importe //from line 0
tab [1] $importe //from line 2
tab [2] $importe //from line 3
tab [3] $importe //from line 4
```

So i can sum all of them and get the average in other variable

Comment: Which of the form values are you trying to sum? Sorry, I can't tell from the script.

Comment: all the script writes several values to text lines in a text file, all of them seperated by | like this name | age | email | quantity. Imagine i have several lines like that in my textfile, now i want to read the $quantity of each line and put them all in the array so i can can sum them

Comment: Please add clarifying details to your question, such as what you posted in the comment above @CesarMedrano

Comment: So what  this line `print"$linea<BR>";` is you gettting

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `$linea[]` an array by adding brackets like this.

`while(!feof($miarchivo)){
    $linea[]=fgets($miarchivo,255);
}`

Then you can access each line like this...

`$linea[0] = "line 1"
$linea[1] = "line 2"`

if you need to print the current line, like you do in your while loop, you can add another temporary variable and print that like this...

`$linea[] = $currentLine = fgets($miarchivo,255);
print($currentLine);`

Answer (score 0):

Export to array then take last value and store in array. Finally add the array and get the average result. Here is your code

```
while(!feof($miarchivo)){
    $linea=fgets($miarchivo,255);
    $quantityArray[] = end(explode('|',$linea));
}

$averageResult = array_sum($quantityArray)/count($quantityArray);
```

Comment: He never asked for an average result though?
He simply wants to capture text values

Comment: @electric.Kariim Read OP's last line `So i can sum all of them and get the average in other variable`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the values in an array to get an average. Unless you need to do something else with that array, it's just a waste of memory. You can sum and count the `$importe` values as you read the lines, and then calculate the average from those values at the end.

```
$count = $sum = 0;
while (($linea = fgetcsv($miarchivo, 0, '|')) !== false) {
    $importe = trim($linea[3]);
    $count++;
    $sum += $importe;
}

if ($count) {  // check count to prevent division by zero
    $average = $sum / $count;
}
```